'Signing' tab not visible on Visual Studio 2022 17.11.5
I am trying to sign my code in Visual Studio 2022 17.11.5 because when I create .exe file and then want to download it, browser detects it as virus, so I cannot share the file this way.
I saw some videos about it and everybody has a "Signing" tab when they click Project -> Properties , but I cannot find it. It is simply not there.
Here is a screenshot after opening Project -> Properties and on left pane should be Signing tab visible but it isn't:

